# Auto Sync Time After Login to Windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, time

For some reason, my PC time become incorrect every time I cold boot my PC. Is there a way to have a command prompt that run automatically to sync the time with server after I cold boot and login to windows? Thank you.

Comment: How far out from correct is it? 10 minutes or Jan 2004?

Comment: @Tetsujin Let say if I shutdown PC on 6pm, tomorrow morning when I turn on PC at 9am, the clock maybe will be 1.20am.

Comment: That will be too much drift to auto-compensate. Change your CMOS battery & see what happens.